# Open New Window on Submit Button with "parent.location"

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time getting a submit button to open a link in a new window.

The button code:

```
<input type="button" name="buy" value="Buy" onClick="parent.location='myurl'" />
```

I tried to add a target="_blank" to the form, but that didn't help.

Is it possible to open a new window using this "parent.location" method or any equivalent.

I'm afraid my shopping cart script won't work any longer if I change the code too much.

Best regards,

Erik Chan

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="whatever" method="post" target="foo" onSubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=1040,height=900,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
```

This should work for your needs.  I have used this time and time again

Answer (score 0):

Try window.open() method.

```
<input type="button" name="buy" value="Buy" onclick="window.open('myurl')">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="buy" value="Buy" onClick='window.open("http://www.abcd.com/")' />
```

see it for open function param
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp